# Replacing multiple items in column with 0 if a statement is true

Tags: vba, excel

```
filename                      ID            Ended On          Sync   Total   ToDo
2016_05_03_10_28_32_xxxx     xxxx    Tue May 3 10:29:57 2016    8     8        0
```

This is a line from a spreadsheet in excel in the project I am working on. How would I replace all instances of `xxxx` in `ID` column with `0` in the spreadsheet if `ToDo=0`. I need to do this for every row.

EDIT:

This file has about 30k lines. How do I write a formula or VBA for: If F2 = 0, to replace all appearances of the text value(B2) in column B with 0. Which then repeats for each row.

Letters represent columns(row 1)

```
    A                         B           C        D    E    F

2016_05_13_23_53_28_xxxx    xxxx     Fri May 13    5    8    3
2016_05_14_05_33_42_xxxx    xxxx     Sat May 14    8    8    0
2016_05_14_07_23_22_yyyy    yyyy     Sat May 14    8    8    0
2016_05_14_07_23_22_yyyy    yyyy     Sat May 14    2    8    6
```

Comment: do you know how to use vba ?

Comment: @cyberponk I have been tinkering with it, but do not have a good understanding

Comment: If you don't have a good understanding of VBA, I would suggest you create a formula in a new column which says `=IF(AND(B2="xxxx",F2=0),0,B2)`, then copy those calculated values over the existing values in column B.  (Column letters in the example are based on the assumption that your example data starts in cell A1 - adjust if necessary.)

Comment: @YowE3K I see what you are doing now, but how do I replace all instances of xxxx with 0 in the entire column B?

Comment: Is xxxx in the filename the same with xxxx in ID?

Comment: Copy that formula down.  E.g. if you typed it in cell G2, copy it all the way down column G to your last row of data.  Then copy / paste special values all of those values to the corresponding cells in column B.

Comment: @YowE3K That does not replace all instances of xxxx in column B

Comment: @Yow3K This file has 30k lines. If F2 = 0, I am trying to replace all appearances of text(B2) in column B with 0.

Comment: By `text(B2)`, do you mean all numbers that have been input as text (e.g. " '1234")?  Or do you mean all values that are non-numeric (such as "56A78")?  Or do you mean something else?

Comment: @bzimor Yes it is

Comment: @YowE3K non-numeric values

Comment: Try using a formula such as `=IF(AND(NOT(ISNUMBER(B2)),F2=0),0,VALUE(B2))`

Comment: @YowE3K this code does not replace B2 in B:B with 0, if F2 = 0.

Comment: What value do you have in B2?

Comment: @YowE3K See edit. If F2 = 0, i want to replace all appearances of B2 in column B with 0

Answer (score 0):

In cell B2 put this and fill down:

```
=IF(F2<>0,RIGHT(A2,4),"0000")
```

Answer (score 0):

Jim, Besides the formula quoted above, this code in VBA will also take care of replacing your data with zeroes:

```
Sub Replace()
Dim i as long
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastrow
    If Cells(i, 2) = "xxxx" And Cells(i, 6) = 0 Then
       Cells(i, 2) = 0
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want all instances of 'xxxx' replaced with zeroes?

Comment: That is all instances from column A?

Comment: I just want to change values in column B. Yes all instances in B to be changed

Comment: Jim, you already know this...but just in case...Follow this: Developer > Insert > ActiveX Controls, and click the commandbutton icon, and draw it on the sheet. Double-clicking this button will take you into VB editor where you'll see two lines: Private Sub CommandButton1_Click(), and End Sub. Now copy the body of code (excluding the first and the last lines) from Sub Replace(), and paste it between Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() and End Sub. Your command button on the sheet is energized. Now, just click it . This is one of the ways in which you can use the code.

Answer (score 0):

you could use [Autofilter()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193884.aspx)

```
Sub main()
    With Worksheets("Zeros") '<-- change "Zeros" to your actual worksheet name
        With .Range("F1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)) '<--| get range in columns "A:F" down to last non empty row in column "A"
            .AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=0 '<--| filter rows by column "F" (the 6th one) on value 0
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1 Then .Offset(, 1).Resize(, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) = 0 '<-- if any rows filtered other than headers one then change their column "B" value to zero
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False '<-- remove dropdowns
    End With
End Sub
```

which should be much faster then looping through cells

Comment: @Jim, did you get through it?